# Why are intersection and union characters inconsistent in multiple fonts?

Tags: font-design, unicode

I wanted to use the Unicode characters:

- U+2229 Intersection
- U+222A Union

They are next to each other in the Unicode table.

Here's how they look on Stack Exchange:

∩∪

And here's what they look like in Arial 48pt in Microsoft Word (with 230% zoom):

[image: Intersection and Union in Arial, Microsoft Word]

It gets different, but not better IMHO, when I switch to Calibri:

[image: Intersection and Union in Calibri, Microsoft Word]

Even Times New Roman is broken:

[image: Intersection and Union in Times New Roman, Microsoft Word]

Doesn't that look ugly and s&%$$y? Shouldn't they have equal heights? I think their shape is distinguishable enough to not mix them up. What's the reasoning behind this? And why is this so consistent across these major fonts?

Comment: Clearly, you need to use a font that specifically comes with these glyphs included.

Comment: Your screenshots look like you’re on Windows, so this may not help, but if you have a macOS machine, you might use an application like [Fonty](https://www.ghostotter.com/os-x-apps/fonty/) to generate a list of all installed fonts that contain both `Intersection` and `Union`, to make it easier to select a good font for your document/project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've got some font substitution going on.

Union doesn't exist in [standard] Arial, [image]

only in Arial Unicode… [image]

where it looks like a perfectly inverted intersection.
…and it's the same for Calibri & Times New Roman.

∩∪ *for copy/paste testing*
btw, depending on platform & font substitution on SE, I don't know what font you will actually see in the copy/paste example. For me it's substituted by Apple Symbol. YMMV, of course.

Comment: Where do I get Arial Unicode from? Isn't that the font installed on Windows by default? It's not in the list of fonts in Word.

Comment: I'm not on Windows & I really don't know where I got it (25 years ago;) it was probably on a Monotype job lot CD that the company used to buy by the cartload. These days it's on fonts.com Oh, apparently it used to be in Office, but was removed. I might have just got it from a 20-year old copy of Office initially.

Comment: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/arial-unicode-ms) "We stopped servicing and updating Arial Unicode and no longer install it as part of Office." - Wow!

Comment: Yup, they gave up ;) Arial was a copy of Helvetica Neue anyway, that I guess MS didn't want to pay the fee for. Caught out twice now. Ironically, I see most of SE in Helvetica Neue, on the Mac. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial for background.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica

Comment: @Tetsujin Arial is most emphatically not a copy of Helvetica! It's actually derived from a Monotype Grotesque (215, I think).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - did you read the Wikipedia page? *"The typeface was designed in 1982, by Robin Nicholas and Patricia Saunders, for Monotype Typography.[5] Each of its characters has the same width as that character in the popular typeface Helvetica; the purpose of this design is to allow a document designed in Helvetica to be displayed and printed with the intended line-breaks and page-breaks without a Helvetica license.  Because of their almost identical appearances, both Arial and Helvetica have commonly been mistaken for each other."* I think that's 'polite-speak' for 'copy' ;)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - it's a license-fee avoider. Both were grotesks initially.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not a copy. There are even questions here about that.

Comment: Tomato tomato.. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Iirc, you're allowed to copy fonts (perhaps even typefaces). Just not the computer programs encoding the fonts. The fact it's not a copy is meaningful.